# How can I pass two values (lat lng) to one parameter key of GET request using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a request call on the Yelp API (https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api). However, I came across a problem with trying to pass in two value of lat lng coordinates to one of the parameter cll. The cll key requires two values of doubles (lat and lng). I've tried creating a string concatenation of both points using a comma as a separator. I also tried using the decodeURI() and encodeURI() method to change the comma but that didnt work either. I also tried passing the value in as an array of two points but that didnt work :/

Here is how I am passing in the parameters using OAUTH to query my paramters.

```
var parameters = [];
parameters.push(['term', term]);
parameters.push(['limit', limit]);
parameters.push(['cll', latlngString]);
// latlngString = (lat.toString() + " , " +lng.toString());
.....

var parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
```

does anyone know what the proper way it is to pass in two values to one key when making a GET request?

Comment: having a quick look at the docs, try removing the spaces in the `" , "` portion of the string. Don't know if it would matter much (never used the yelp api) but give that a shot and let me know.

Comment: I dont think that will work cause then it would just read it as one value instead of 2 different lat lng points

Comment: Please note I said removing the _spaces_ not removing the entire string.

Comment: oh woops sorry about that. but yeah i tried that as well, but still no luck. the url request reads the comma as the hexadecimal value %2C and thus why i tried decoding that and passing that instead of the comma, which I had no luck with as well

Comment: what is the URL of the request you make with the given parameters?

Comment: okay, trying to fiddle around with this in postman but apparently yelp are ... unkind... in this regard. give me a second.

Comment: https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?callback=cb&term=food&limit=5&cll=33.1866159649979%2C-117.35905740908515&callback=cb
I have deleted some parts of it because it contained my secret key

Comment: sweet thanks @Jhecht for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* (keyword) I've got it, and it's probably one of the silliest/most annoying things I've ever seen.

Take the address you gave me

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?callback=cb&term=food&limit=5&cll=33.1866159649979%2C-117.35905740908515&callback=cb
```

Obviously, you've edited out the secret key and other information that gets passed from the oAuth and whatever else. couple of random things is that you have the `callback=cb` portion in there twice, which while it shouldn't theoretically cause any issue server-side, it isn't *technically* correct.

The **biggest** thing is that ***you didn't include a location variable***

I've taken your request into postman, added in my own credentials (and having 0 idea where those lat and longitudes lead, just plugged in the closest city to me, San Francisco), obviously with my info stripped off of it, this is the request I am sending. Note the only difference is that I have a location variable being passed. (even tested this with `" , "` and `","` and i still get the same response back, so the first recommendation didn't really change anything)

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&limit=5&cll=33.1866159649979%2C-117.35905740908515&location=San%20Francisco
```

The response back from postman was the following:

```
{
    "region": {
        "span": {
            "latitude_delta": 0.017412363835347833,
            "longitude_delta": 0.02850394313139759
        },
        "center": {
            "latitude": 37.78660181083425,
            "longitude": -122.408286062213
        }
    },
    "total": 13061,
    "businesses": [{
        "is_claimed": true,
        "rating": 4.5,
        "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.com/biz/southern-comfort-kitchen-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
        "review_count": 115,
        "name": "Southern Comfort Kitchen",
        "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/southern-comfort-kitchen-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "categories": [["Food Trucks", "foodtrucks"], ["Cajun/Creole", "cajun"]],
        "phone": "5105496155",
        "snippet_text": "Heard about their amazing southern fried chicken sandwich from my coworkers. So when their truck came around I had to try it! \n\nThe southern fried chicken...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Zxsno5qdvyZvXuD7C1WC2Q/ms.jpg",
        "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/yIuFnDaqwBmeRv_ihUcufw/ms.jpg",
        "display_phone": "+1-510-549-6155",
        "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
        "id": "southern-comfort-kitchen-san-francisco",
        "is_closed": false,
        "location": {
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "display_address": ["Hayes Valley", "San Francisco, CA 94102"],
            "geo_accuracy": 5.0,
            "neighborhoods": ["Hayes Valley", "Civic Center"],
            "postal_code": "94102",
            "country_code": "US",
            "address": [],
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 37.78291,
                "longitude": -122.41352
            },
            "state_code": "CA"
        }
    }, {
        "is_claimed": true,
        "rating": 4.5,
        "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.com/biz/tacorea-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
        "review_count": 366,
        "name": "Tacorea",
        "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tacorea-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "categories": [["Mexican", "mexican"], ["Korean", "korean"], ["Latin American", "latin"]],
        "menu_date_updated": 1472899698,
        "phone": "4158851325",
        "snippet_text": "We were staying a week in SAN Francisco a few blocks from this place. As MN natives living in an area with amazing Mexican food we needed to experience the...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/7sOn8_P7Hxb0ZkM55tz3mg/ms.jpg",
        "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/S_KZiQ1wHkS0D469bXVDdA/ms.jpg",
        "display_phone": "+1-415-885-1325",
        "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
        "menu_provider": "single_platform",
        "id": "tacorea-san-francisco",
        "is_closed": false,
        "location": {
            "cross_streets": "Taylor St \u0026 Mason St",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "display_address": ["809 Bush St", "Union Square", "San Francisco, CA 94108"],
            "geo_accuracy": 9.5,
            "neighborhoods": ["Union Square", "Lower Nob Hill"],
            "postal_code": "94108",
            "country_code": "US",
            "address": ["809 Bush St"],
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 37.789806,
                "longitude": -122.410709
            },
            "state_code": "CA"
        }
    }, {
        "is_claimed": true,
        "rating": 4.5,
        "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.com/biz/hot-sauce-and-panko-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
        "review_count": 783,
        "name": "Hot Sauce and Panko",
        "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/hot-sauce-and-panko-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "categories": [["Chicken Wings", "chicken_wings"], ["Specialty Food", "gourmet"]],
        "menu_date_updated": 1472730119,
        "phone": "4153591908",
        "snippet_text": "If I can give this place more than 5 stars, I WOULD! I LA LA LA LOVE HOT SAUCE AND PANKO!  Coming here, I was not expecting much. In fact, when my friend...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/vKQD4EF6xk7_ryHtgiTAJA/ms.jpg",
        "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/nAggqOjIiqELwX2D_RRRag/ms.jpg",
        "display_phone": "+1-415-359-1908",
        "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
        "menu_provider": "single_platform",
        "id": "hot-sauce-and-panko-san-francisco",
        "is_closed": false,
        "location": {
            "cross_streets": "Washington St \u0026 Jackson St",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "display_address": ["1468 Hyde St", "Nob Hill", "San Francisco, CA 94109"],
            "geo_accuracy": 9.5,
            "neighborhoods": ["Nob Hill"],
            "postal_code": "94109",
            "country_code": "US",
            "address": ["1468 Hyde St"],
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 37.7945165216685,
                "longitude": -122.417876198887
            },
            "state_code": "CA"
        }
    }, {
        "is_claimed": true,
        "rating": 4.5,
        "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.com/biz/hrd-san-francisco-4?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
        "review_count": 1951,
        "name": "HRD",
        "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/hrd-san-francisco-4?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "categories": [["Asian Fusion", "asianfusion"], ["Latin American", "latin"], ["Middle Eastern", "mideastern"]],
        "menu_date_updated": 1481879601,
        "phone": "4155432355",
        "snippet_text": "Korean Mexican fusion at its finest! I ordered the eggplant katsu in a po' boy and it was delicious (but that might be because I'm partial to eggplant)....",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ImvLt9I8ACHwfYthZw8vVw/ms.jpg",
        "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/LmU4LKuS7iq8kxxcI3lwDw/ms.jpg",
        "display_phone": "+1-415-543-2355",
        "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
        "menu_provider": "eat24",
        "id": "hrd-san-francisco-4",
        "is_closed": false,
        "location": {
            "cross_streets": "Taber Aly \u0026 Park Ave",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "display_address": ["521A 3rd St", "SoMa", "San Francisco, CA 94107"],
            "geo_accuracy": 9.5,
            "neighborhoods": ["SoMa"],
            "postal_code": "94107",
            "country_code": "US",
            "address": ["521A 3rd St"],
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 37.7811065758548,
                "longitude": -122.395329724426
            },
            "state_code": "CA"
        }
    }, {
        "is_claimed": true,
        "rating": 4.5,
        "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.com/biz/box-kitchen-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
        "review_count": 431,
        "name": "Box Kitchen",
        "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
        "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/box-kitchen-san-francisco?adjust_creative=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=0fHKR3k58xfH-pxKxYNQdw",
        "categories": [["Food Stands", "foodstands"], ["Burgers", "burgers"]],
        "phone": "4155807170",
        "snippet_text": "Pretty much what most folks have said on here.  I love that you walk up to a door and order your food in an alley.  Bottom line is that the food is...",
        "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/RgSY7vrLUfwWRh0-KuUpKQ/ms.jpg",
        "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/4KoZLFB1sEYvTd9baSa2lg/ms.jpg",
        "display_phone": "+1-415-580-7170",
        "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
        "id": "box-kitchen-san-francisco",
        "is_closed": false,
        "location": {
            "cross_streets": "5th St \u0026 Mary St",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "display_address": ["431 Natoma St", "SoMa", "San Francisco, CA 94103"],
            "geo_accuracy": 9.5,
            "neighborhoods": ["SoMa"],
            "postal_code": "94103",
            "country_code": "US",
            "address": ["431 Natoma St"],
            "coordinate": {
                "latitude": 37.7811510761365,
                "longitude": -122.40636505138
            },
            "state_code": "CA"
        }
    }]
}
```

**Also!** I made the same credentialed request (after looking up where those lat/long coordinates are) and just changed the location to San Diego.

Comment: ah yeah i misread the documentation. I had thought that we were able to pass in an alternative lat lng points instead of the location. 
thanks for the help!
but sadly, when i add the location parameter and include the lat lng coordinates, i dont think the lat lng are being used, but instead is always using the location parameter still when it does the search.

Comment: I think the lat and long are meant to be a reference point. Realistically I've not done a whole lot with Yelp API so Im afraid I cant be more helpful.